# Set a timer in R to execute a program

Tags: r, timer

I have a program to execute per 15 seconds, how can I achieve this, the program is as followed:

```
print_test<-function{
    cat("hello world")
}
```

Comment: See `?Sys.sleep` for pausing execution for a specified number of seconds. Otherwise consider scheduled tasks under Windows, or using cron on a linux/unix system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I use for executing same code block every 15 seconds:

```
interval = 15
x = data.frame()

repeat {
  startTime = Sys.time()
  x = rbind.data.frame(x, sum(data)) #replace this line with your code/functions
  sleepTime = startTime + interval - Sys.time()
  if (sleepTime > 0)
    Sys.sleep(sleepTime)
}
```

`x` and `data` are dummy which you need to replace accordingly. This will execute indefinitely until stopped by user. If you need to stop and start at specific times then you need a `for` loop instead of 'repeat`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
print_test<-function(x)
{ 
Sys.sleep(x)
cat("hello world")
}

print_test(15)
```

If you want to execute it for a certain amount of iterations use to incorporate a 'for loop' in your function with the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
print_test<-function(x)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        Sys.sleep(x);
        cat("hello world");
        print_test(x);
    }
}
print_test(15)
```

In this, a function is calling itself after the seconds passed as argument given the condition evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use like this:

```
h <- function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(i)
  print("Hello world!")
}

timer <- function(i) {
  while (T) {
    h(i)
  }
} # Timer function
```